# How to avoid external call in JUnit Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, junit

Finally I am able to get Groovy class in my Java file and able to perform JUnit on my groovy classes. Now my problem is I want to test my method which triggers RPC calls.but I want to avoid that call in unit test. How should I do that? Below is my sample code for logout how I am proceeding

```
@Test
public void logoutTest() {
    GroovyObject loginOject =new Login();
    GroovyObject logoutObject =new Logout();
    XMLRPCServerProxy serverProxy = (XMLRPCServerProxy) loginOject.invokeMethod(
        "getServerProxy",
        "https://urlproxy"
    );
    String sessionId = (String) loginOject.invokeMethod(
        "getSession",
        new Object[]{"username","password",serverProxy}
    );
    logoutObject.invokeMethod("logout",new Object[]{sessionId,serverProxy});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using mocks. I assume you are testing `logoutObject.invokeMethod("logout",new Object[]{sessionId,serverProxy});` method which calls a method on your `XMLRPCServerProxy serverProxy`. If you a have an option to introduce a dependency on mocking framework such as [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) you can then create a mock instead of

```
XMLRPCServerProxy serverProxy = (XMLRPCServerProxy) oginOject.invokeMethod("getServerProxy", "https://urlproxy");
```

You can mock it

```
XMLRPCServerProxy serverProxy = mock(XMLRPCServerProxy.class);
when(serverProxy.sendRequest("payload")).thenReturn("result");
```

If you cannot use a mock library you can extend `XMLRPCServerProxy` in the test and override a method that does rpc call to do whatever you want (this is effectively what Mockito would do for you)

```
XMLRPCServerProxy proxyServer = new XMLRPCServerProxy() {
        public String request(String payload) {
            // your mock code
            return "result";
        }
    };
```

Comment: But that are my groovy files. can I invoke with mockito like direct normal java class??

Comment: In here you are passing `String sessionId = (String) loginOject.invokeMethod("getSession",new Object[]{"username","password",serverProxy})` server proxy so if it will be mocked it should still be working the same. I am not very familiar with the groovy but  if can get that object in this Java code and pass it back into your groovy code it should not matter what that object is.

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: I've edited a comment to give more explanation. Initially I posted a comment by hitting enter to move to a new line and I dodn't know that it will cause the comment to be posted.

Comment: To enter a linebreak you have to press Shift+Enter. Unfortunately only until you send it, because SO strips away the linebreaks and again does the whole comment in one line.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Spock for unit-testing Groovy (and Java) code. Latest when it comes to mocking, no Java tool / framework I know is capable of properly mocking Groovy stuff as the language is simply too dynamic to be handled by tools written to hook into Java code.

Spock is written in Groovy and with Groovy in mind when it comes to mocking and stubbing. Spock might look a bit alien if you first look at it, but if you get used to the syntax it is quite amazing what you can do and how easy you can write tests with variying input data and so on.

Spock also is based on JUnit, so every tool that is able to execute and evaluate JUnit tests is also able to cope with Spock tests.